# regex replacement in stream with Java

Tags: java

Consider following snipped code

```
InputStream in = resource.getInputStream();
try {
        StreamUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
        }
}
```

I want before copy to output stream find all things that match with this pattern ${something} (start with "${" and end with "}") and replace it with another thing that I put in the map.

Consider my input stream is something like this

```
<label value="${key1}" />
<label value="${key2}" />
```

I want output stream is something like this:

```
<label value="AAAAA" />
<label value="BBBBB" />
```

and of course my stream is large.

Comment: Explain what you try to achieve. Add the __WHAT__, preferable with a small example. Then give some hint about the __HOW__, you tried to solve the question.

Comment: try this regexp:        \${.*}

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for SedInputStream or SedOutputStream (which I have never seen implemented). Although perhaps there is a pointer in the right direction here: http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/unix-commands-implemented-grep-wc-cat.139160/

Answer (score 0):

You need to read stream to the String, replace using `string.replaceAll("regexp", "replacement")` and write it to the output stream.

Comment: This is quick and easy, but of course does not scale nicely to large streams (because you will run out of memory).

Answer (score 0):

^\${.*}

This regexp match all lines start with ${........any chars here.......}

Answer (score 0):

i think you already have a map of values that you want to put in. then you can do something like

```
Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("substr1", "repl1");
        put("substr2", "repl2");
        put("substr3", "repl3");
    }};

    String input = "lorem substr1 ipsum substr2 dolor substr3 amet";

    // create the pattern joining the keys with '|'
    String regexp = "substr1|substr2|substr3";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacements.get(m.group()));
    m.appendTail(sb);


    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

you can also dynamically build the string regexp if you want by iterating over the keys